# What is the best approach here?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

The question in context is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56745097/10155936).

I had posted an answer to this question on five months ago. However, a few months later I received a comment on the answer saying that it is not a valid answer. I took this feedback and tried to answer the question again.

However, I received a similar comment on my new answer without any explanation. How do I ask the user to give a scenario where the answer won't apply, or what can I do so that answer is best understood by others?

---

*Another comment (which gave the scenario where it didn't work) by the same user helped improved the answer though.*

Comment: It's fun that the person telling you also referenced that one in his answer ...

Comment: Do you really have to? Someone posting a comment does not mean they're right

Comment: *"and tried to answer the question again"* .... you can edit your question, use that instead of creating a new answer post.

Comment: The title needs work. It makes the question unclear. *"What is the best approach here?"* - Best approach to/for what?

Answer (score 13):

It's their word against yours. Don't focus on one individual too much. If they have a point, they should elaborate. If you think you're correct to the best of your knowledge and nobody has proven you wrong yet, then don't lose sleep over it. If you're indeed wrong, the community is supposed to figure that out and vote and comment accordingly. **Just [let it go](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L0MK7qz13bU).**

Comment: Better not follow that link when sitting in an open office space. Or make at least sure  you're pitch perfect ...

Comment: It reminds me of this xkcd [comic](https://xkcd.com/386/)

Comment: @Saurabh Yeah, that's probably both of you right now… 

Comment: Well said. If someone can't tell you why you're "wrong", especially in a community such as SO, it normally says to me that they have been told that *X* is wrong, without explanation in the past and never researched it their-self. You can't take anything now a days as "gospal", and the best way we can all learn if by being told the "why", right or *wrong*. Just being told "that's not right", doesn't help any of us grow and that includes the person that asked the question too; if an answer is "wrong" and no one knows why, then not even the OP can learn from that other persons "experience".